# IPython Console - Remove Line Number In[#] at Begining of line?

Tags: python, console, ipython, spyder

I am just starting out with Spyder, and noticed in the IPython console in the lower left hand side of the screen, it always displays "In [#]" at the beginning of every line output.

So it would say

`In[1] print("ugh")
ugh
In[2]`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8UYh.jpg

I was just wondering is there anyway to remove this at the beginning of the line?

Comment: Any particular reason you want to do that? Distinguishing input from output is important, and this is how IPython does it.

Comment: Better yet it shows `Out[1]` for output lines.  What do you want it to show?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I don't know if you can completely remove them, but you can modify them by going to the menu `Tools > Preferences > IPython console > Advanced Settings > Prompts`. Please put the mouse over the `Input/Output prompt` text fields to see the syntax you need to use to change them.

Comment: Its a personal preference thing to be honest - I like the fact that it shows the [In] and [Out] as it makes reading the execution a lot easier. I just find seeing [In #] after a certain period of time difficult to read. So I just wanted to remove the trailing # after the [In/Out]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Carlos 

I see the default for the input prompt is: <span class="in-prompt-number">%i</span> 

I tried to put this in the location specified: <span class="in-prompt-number"></span>

I just simply removed the %i and it did not seem to make a difference. I still see [In #]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the input and output prompts in the setting (IPython console → Advanced settings → Prompts):
[image]

If you hover over the "Input prompt: " field you will see that the default value is:

```
In [<span class="in-prompt-number">%i</span>]:
```

You can change that to a single space   if you want nothing to show there, or write your own custom message. Press Apply or OK.

Now restart the IPython console or open a new console.

For demonstration purposes I changed it to the text `This is a test:`

[image]

Which results in:
[image]