# How can I show the conda environment name in the IPython console?

Tags: python, spyder

### Context

I would like to show the conda environment name in the IPython console of Spyder, so I know which environment I'm running in.
While this information is available in the status bar, it sometimes just shows `conda` instead of the actual environment name:

[image]

### What I've tried

#### Printing it at startup

Spyder allows one to run code at the start of a console. However, it seems print statements are suppressed as I've added `import sys; print(sys.executable)`:

[image]

Unfortunately nothing is shown (besides the default banner) when I create a new console.

#### Changing the input prompt

Spyder [allows one to customize the input/output prompts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68197103/1256347) in the console. However, I can't figure out how to let it evaluate code instead of writing it as text:

[image]

[image]

### Question

How to show the name of the active conda environment in the IPython console of Spyder?

Comment: Maybe the comments in this issue https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/15881 could be useful for a temporal workaround. The current discussion in this topic is at: https://github.com/spyder-ide/ux-improvements/issues/10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion to look at the [relevant issue](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/15881) ([this comment in particular](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/15881#issuecomment-862356142)) has brought me the following solution:

```py
import sys; 
env_path = sys.executable
start_env = env_path.rfind('\\', 0, len(env_path) - 12) 
end_env = env_path.rfind('\\')
env_name = env_path[start_env+1:end_env]
get_ipython().banner1=f"\nCurrent conda environment: {env_name}"
```

By saving above in a file and setting it as the python startup file in the Spyder settings:

[image]

I now get a nice message informing me of the conda environment that is used:

[image]